# How can I calculate TOTAL_PRICE based on time in PHP

Tags: php, html

I need to calculate `$total_price` which is equal to number of days selected multiplied the price`(date_to-date_from)*$price`. I take the `date` from `html` with `method="POST"`

so : `$total_price=($_POST['date_to'] - $_POST['date_from'])*price`

I don't have the idea on how can I get the difference between this 2 dates and the get this number as an integer and then multiplie it buy the price.

Date format `mm/dd/yyyy`.

So for example if the first selected date is `01/01/2020` and and the second selected date is `02/01/2020` , `price=30` , then we get `total=31*30=930;`

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: There are several duplicates on how to find the number of days between two dates. Read the information linked to your question and you will find the answer.

Comment: Alright I will try

Comment: Thanks for your help. This code works fine ```$date_from = strtotime($_POST['date_from']);
        $date_to = strtotime($_POST['date_to']);
          $date_from = date('d-m-y', $date_from);
          $date_to = date('d-m-y', $date_to);
          $datediff = abs($date_to - $date_from);
          $a= floor($datediff);
          $total_price=$a*30;
          echo $total_price;``` but only if I select dates from the same months. I need to make this total_price be correct if I select dates from different months.